# Displays the same image with fancybox plugins on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, fancybox, each

I have some buttons with same id - previewPhoto. I'm using fancybox to display photo. But all button displays the same image. Where could be a problem, my 'photo' and 'id' vars are different.

```
$(function() {
    $('button#previewPhoto').each(function() {
        photo = $(this).val();
        id = $(this).attr("title");
        link = 'http://domain.com/members/photos/'+id+'/'+photo;
        $(this).click(function() {
            $.fancybox({
                //'orig'            : $(this),
                'padding'       : 0,
                'href'          : link,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique on a page. Use a class instead.

Comment: I've changed to class, but situation is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `.each()`, simply do this :

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".previewPhoto").on("click", function () {
        var photo = $(this).val(),
            id = this.title,
            link = 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/' + id + '/' + photo;
        $.fancybox(link, {
            // API options here
        });
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/454QF/1)**

**NOTE**: `.on()` requires jQuery v.1.7+